# How to document Protractor e2e tests?

Tags: angularjs, protractor

I would like to know about any ways and best practices to document protractor tests.I mean inline documentation similar to jsDoc or phpDoc I'am using the Page Object pattern for protractor tests. Please suggest a method for inline documentation for both  the spec files and page object files.

Comment: You mean, you need to document test results?

Comment: @QualityProducts. I meant to document the working of a code form developer perspective similar to phpDoc or JsDoc. So that other developers can easily understand my automation code.